# How to model Mixture of Bernoullis in pymc3

Tags: pymc3, pymc, dirichlet

I'm trying to use Dirichlet Processes to identify clusters in my binary data. I'm using the [tutorial](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/dp_mix.html) as a starting point, but the tutorial is framed where the outcome is a mixture of 1D normal or poisson distributed variables.

I have multiple binary variables per observation, 5 in the example code below, and cannot work out how to frame the final mixture step. From the mathematical description in [this report](https://cs.brown.edu/research/pubs/theses/masters/2015/ni.mengrui.pdf) I can see the overall likelihood is simply the product of the likelihoods across all the assigned clusters.

I haven't explicitly formed cluster labels (using `Categorical(w)`) as the `pm.Mixture` distribution handles this, but can't work out how to formulate the likelihood as a probability model that pymc3 understands.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pymc3 as pm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from theano import tensor as tt

N = 100
P = 5
K_ACT = 3

# Simulate 5 variables with 100 observations of each that fit into 3 groups
mu_actual = np.array([[0.7, 0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.5],
                      [0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6],
                      [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3]])
cluster_ratios = [0.6, 0.2, 0.2]  

df = np.concatenate([np.random.binomial(1, mu_actual[0, :], size=(int(N*cluster_ratios[0]), P)),
                     np.random.binomial(1, mu_actual[1, :], size=(int(N*cluster_ratios[1]), P)),
                     np.random.binomial(1, mu_actual[2, :], size=(int(N*cluster_ratios[2]), P))])

# Deterministic function for stick breaking
def stick_breaking(beta):
    portion_remaining = tt.concatenate([[1], tt.extra_ops.cumprod(1 - beta)[:-1]])
    return beta * portion_remaining

K_THRESH = 20

with pm.Model() as model:
    # The DP priors to obtain w, the cluster weights
    alpha = pm.Gamma('alpha', 1., 1.)
    beta = pm.Beta('beta', 1, alpha, shape=K_THRESH)
    w = pm.Deterministic('w', stick_breaking(beta))

    # Each variable should have a probability parameter for each cluster
    mu = pm.Beta('mu', 1, 1, shape=(K_THRESH, P))

    obs = pm.Mixture('obs', w, pm.Bernoulli.dist(mu), observed=df)

with model:
    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(100, step=step, random_seed=17)

pm.traceplot(trace, varnames=['alpha', 'w'])
```

**EDIT 28/01/2019**

I've provided a custom likelihood function that simply calculates the Bernoulli mixture likelihood after drawing component labels from a Categorical distribution. However, while the model is now doing something, it can't identify the 3 groups, instead only finding 2. I can't tell if it just needs more sampling / more efficient parameterisation, or whether the model definition is flawed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pymc3 as pm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from theano import tensor as tt

N = 1000
P = 5

# Simulate 5 variables with 1000 observations of each that fit into 3 groups
mu_actual = np.array([[0.7, 0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.5],
                      [0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6],
                      [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3]])
cluster_ratios = [0.4, 0.3, 0.3]  

df = np.concatenate([np.random.binomial(1, mu_actual[0, :], size=(int(N*cluster_ratios[0]), P)),
                     np.random.binomial(1, mu_actual[1, :], size=(int(N*cluster_ratios[1]), P)),
                     np.random.binomial(1, mu_actual[2, :], size=(int(N*cluster_ratios[2]), P))])

# Deterministic function for stick breaking
def stick_breaking(beta):
    portion_remaining = tt.concatenate([[1], tt.extra_ops.cumprod(1 - beta)[:-1]])
    return beta * portion_remaining

K_THRESH = 20

def bernoulli_mixture_loglh(comp, mus):
    # K = maximum number clusters
    # N = number observations (1000 here)
    # P = number predictors (5 here)
    # Shape of tensors:
    #   comp: K
    #   mus: K, P
    #   value (data): N, P
    def loglh_(value):
        mus_comp = mus[comp, :]
        # These are (NxK) matrices giving likelihood contributions
        # from each observation according to each component's probability
        # parameter (mu)
        pos = value * tt.log(mus_comp)
        neg = (1-value) * tt.log((1-mus_comp))
        comb = pos + neg
        overall_sum = tt.sum(comb)
        return overall_sum
    return loglh_

with pm.Model() as model:
    # The DP priors to obtain w, the cluster weights
    alpha = pm.Gamma('alpha', 1., 1.)
    beta = pm.Beta('beta', 1, alpha, shape=K_THRESH)
    w = pm.Deterministic('w', stick_breaking(beta))
    component = pm.Categorical('component', w, shape=N)

    # Each variable should have a probability parameter for each cluster
    mu = pm.Beta('mu', 1, 1, shape=(K_THRESH, P))
    obs = pm.DensityDist('obs', bernoulli_mixture_loglh(component, mu), observed=df)   

n_samples = 5000
burn = 500
thin = 10

with model:
    step1 = pm.Metropolis(vars=[alpha, beta, w, mu])
    step2 = pm.ElemwiseCategorical([component], np.arange(K_THRESH))
    trace_ = pm.sample(n_samples, [step1, step2], sample=17)

trace = trace_[burn::thin]

pm.traceplot(trace)
plt.show()
```

**Should the w trace be stationary?**

[image: traces]

```
# Plot weights per component
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

plot_w = np.arange(K_THRESH) + 1

ax.bar(plot_w - 0.5, trace['w'].mean(axis=0), width=1., lw=0);

ax.set_xlim(0.5, K_THRESH);
ax.set_xlabel('Component');
ax.set_ylabel('Posterior expected mixture weight');
```

**Why aren't the components ordered? In other examples I've seen they are typically arranged in descending size order**

[image: components]

**The code below displays the mu Bernoulli parameter values for the 2 main components, but these are far from the actual values**

```
# Posterior values of mu for the non-zero components
mean_w = np.mean(trace['w'], axis=0)
nonzero_component = np.where(mean_w > 0.3)[0]

mean_mu = np.mean(trace['mu'], axis=0)
print(mean_mu[nonzero_component, :])

[[0.47587256 0.50065195 0.51081395 0.57693177 0.40762681]
 [0.42596485 0.69626519 0.5629946  0.30185575 0.64322441]]
```

Actual parameters used to simulate data:

```
[[0.7, 0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.5],
 [0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6],
 [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3]]
```